# Why is the Lonely Planet Mongolian phrasebook so small?

Tags: mongolian-language, phrasebooks

Lonely Planet's Mongolian Phrasebook & Dictionary has only [212 pages](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1743211848), while [Japanese](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1743214405) has 272 pages, and Chinese has [256 pages](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/174321197X). Also, the Mongolian phrasebook does not have some sections that other phrasebooks have. (In fairness, the phrasebook also has some sections that are specifically about Mongolian topics)

Is this because Mongolian phrasebooks are less commonly purchased than other languages, and they deal with the reduced revenue by creating less content?

Am I likely to encounter this with other Lonely Planet phrasebooks about less popular languages, and/or with other publishers' phrasebooks about Mongolian?

Comment: Languages do not have the same number of words, phrases, etc, so language books will be different sizes.  Plus some languages are more simplistic, so what we need ten words to say in English, they say with just three words, thus taking up less space.

Comment: A remarkable question!  Andrew, I'd suggest that the variation you bring to light (pages: 212, 272, 256) is, in fact, **a typical variation** within book series, whether in the field of travel books, or, other similar sets of books on a theme.

Comment: Secondly, "Mongolian phrasebooks are less commonly purchased than other languages" that is almost certainly the case. But: "by creating less content"... content is very cheap to produce for titles like this.  Let's say theoretically (for whatever reason) someone in the product line said "I want 200 pages added to this particular title, the Mongolian book".  In fact, it would cost almost nothing to do that. It's completely possible that (let's say) internally at the company there was very little interest in that particular title, so, quite simply nobody bothered making it very long....but....

Comment: ...but, regarding specifically "the cost in dollars of making it longer, creating more or less content", I'd say no, that's a non-issue.  Finally, "Am I likely to encounter this... etc" I'd come back to my first point, I'd say such variation is pretty common in a given "book set" of some description, so, I very much doubt you could find a generalisation there.  So, you **would not** find a generalisation: "in the language book publishing field, the less popular languages have shorter related books." ... I'd guess!

Comment: @JoeBlow No offense, but you're pulling this out of your ass.  Commissioning, editing and laying out content accounts for the bulk of a book's cost and is all costed on a per-page basis, so publishers watch their page counts like hawks, and one of the worst sins for a travel author is to exceed their allocated page count.  This applies to phrasebooks too.

Comment: I actually think that in this case they're really not making new editions of the Mongolian book but just reprinting the same content with a new cover design every few years. It must keep selling or they wouldn't even have to do that. But it's certainly not one of their more popular titles, which get completely overhauled every few years. The new editions tend to get fatter to compete with new editions by other publishers. But for Mongolian there's no competition. I've got a collection of about thirty LP phrasebooks of various ages.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Very roughly speaking, the size of *any* non-fiction book is determined by two competing factors: the publisher wants to print as little as possible to reduce costs (not just printing, but writing, editing, layout etc) and sell it at the highest price possible, while the reader wants to buy as big a book as possible at the lowest price possible.  And the marketplace works out an equilibrium somewhere in the middle.

For guidebooks (and phrasebooks), the amount of content necessary is determined by **the size of the place and its popularity with tourists**.  Mongolia is small (populationwise), rather obscure, and there isn't a whole lot of competition, so books will tend towards the skinnier end of the spectrum.

Source: I used to work for several guidebook publishers.

Comment: For something such as a phrasebook, I suppose it might even be that that particular title is losing money for the publisher, but they keep it alive anyway in order to support (a perception of) completeness of coverage in their series that will help drive sales of more profitable titles (with more competition).

Comment: +1, though I'm not sure about the assumption that travelers want to buy as big a book as possible. When I'm traveling, _compactness_ of the reference works I bring (and have to carry everywhere) is a significant priority.

Comment: @HenningMakholm You (and I) might think so, but the travel bestseller lists are still dominated by 1000-page potboilers like the Europe and South-East Asia shoestring guides.

Comment: Although I agreee with you in the general view that publishers want to reduce size and clients want to maximize, I don't think this holds true for traveling books. At least I want the smallest book possible with the largest amount of information possible. It's up to the content and design team to acomplish it :)

Comment: @nsn Andrew was asking about page count. Compare paper weight and font size between a travel guide and a X for Dummies book to see how you can have lots of pages with little weight...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "Modern Mongolian: A Course Book" by Dr John Gaunt? It's very straightforward, pronunciation of every letter is compared to a similar sound of English words and the grammar explained clearly, not in complicated ways as some other books do. Sometimes they sell copies with audio tapes included. (Sorry, I repeated my answer here). 
I found Mongolian Phrase books are usually not very satisfactory.
Probably there are some ways to have language lessons via Skype or something?

Comment: Phrasebooks and language courses target different audiences. If you're in the country for a week and need to communicate travel basics, a phrasebook is perfect. If you're staying longer and want to actually learn/speak the language, get a course book.